# The crontab not running inside container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job inside the container to run a ruby class, but it's not running automatically.
When I'm trying to test it locally without docker and container, it works great. And also when running the following command `rails runner "Delete.delete_old_requests"` in the terminal and it works.

I think the problem in the app path! which is called myapp. Thanks in advance

1. I install the cron inside the container. `apt-get install cron`
2. create a task in a ruby file called Delete.rb. and a method called delete_old_requests
3. create a cron task in crontab file as shown below:

```
* * * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails runner "Delete.delete_old_requests"'
```

the code:
delete.rb

```
class Delete < ApplicationRecord
    def self.delete_old_requests
         users=User.all
         users.update_all(requests_num_per_day: 0)
    end
end
```

crontab

```
* * * * *  /bin/bash -l -c '/myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails runner "Delete.delete_old_requests"'
```

Comment: As mentioned in the possible duplicate question, running cron in foreground will help `cron -f`. Go through that question.

Comment: Or you could simply use [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). Works inside docker out of the box.